# git submodule error

Tags: git, git-submodules

Getting this error:

```
fatal: cannot read object aab1ca8db3ab8f1508db42220f9badc7b62dd4aa 'vendor/plugins/simple_stuff': It is a submodule!
```

When doing `git pull` from the main repo.
I don't have any submodule defined any where inside my project, still I have another repo inside `vendor/plugins/simple_stuff`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the "[git submodules gotcha](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2009/03/git-submodule-gotcha/)" article, did you try a

```
 $ git pull -s resolve
```

(the 'resolve' merge strategy may be able to avoid that message)
(Someone may have reorganized the sources and define a submodule, pushing it to your remote repo from which you are now trying to pull)